# C# Parse float from not-only-numerical string

Tags: c#, regex, parsing

I receive a formatted string and I can't change the source ; it look something like this :

```
{
"value": 4.12
}
```

I have to parse it into a double to show only the number. 
I get I should clean it with a `regex` before using `double.TryParse()`, but I have no idea how to format the regex...

Comment: if source is a JSON string, deserialize it to obtain property value

Comment: aren't you missing a double quote around the `value`?

Comment: If you want to learn regular expressions, the resources on the internet for doing so would literally reach to the moon and back.

Comment: quick and dirty: `double result = double.Parse(Regex.Match(source, @"[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+").Value);`

Comment: @Leonardo yes indeed, I edited the question

Comment: @KarthikGanesan Can you do it in Fortran too?

Answer (score 2):

if you only missed a double-quotes around the `value`, that is a valid JSON. You can parse it using almost any json library.

Comment: Doesn't look like valid JSON to me, although I didn't downvote you

Comment: @KSib i think he missed the double-quotes only... common typo...

Comment: Looks like you were correct. I upvoted you as well to counter that downvote. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

With [LINQ to JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryingLINQtoJSON.htm) you may retrieve the value in one line:

```
var json = @"{
    ""value"" : 4.12
}";
var value = (double)JObject.Parse(json)["value"];
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/e0viPY

**P.S.**

Since Json.NET accepts more relaxed syntax, this code would work even with the original question edition (i.e. unquoted key):

```
var json = "{ value : 4.12 }";
var value = (double)JObject.Parse(json)["value"];
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/iLERPb

Answer (score 0):

you can use below regex -

[0-9]+(.[0-9][0-9]?)?

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty *regular expression* soluition:

```
  string source = @"{
     ""value"": 4.12
  }";

  double result = double.Parse(Regex.Match(source, @"-?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+").Value,
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

A better implementation, however, is to decerialize it as JSON